# How to sum numbers in arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays

In php, how do I get the total number of posts (16)?

```
array1("posts" => 2, "reactions" => 0)

array2("posts" => 4, "reactions" => 4)

array3("posts" => 7, "reactions" => 0)

array4("posts" => 3, "reactions" => 1)
```

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors, what is the code that you actually run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this function
 `array_merge_recursive`
And I made an example for you

```
<?php
$a = array("posts" => 2, "reactions" => 0);
$b = array("posts" => 4, "reactions" => 4);
$c = array("posts" => 7, "reactions" => 0);
$d = array("posts" => 3, "reactions" => 1);
$array = array_merge_recursive($a,$b,$c,$d); 
$sum = array_sum($array['posts']); 
echo $sum; 
?>
```

If you want to read more about `array_merge_recursive`

Follow this [Link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

Comment: instead of the foreach couldn't you just do 

$sum = array_sum($array['posts']);

Answer (score 3):

Don't know how your variables are named, but some sort of:

```
 $total = 0;
 foreach ($arrayofstuff as $item) {
     $total += $item['posts'];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$numposts = $arr1["posts"]+$arr2["posts"]+$arr3["posts"]+$arr4["posts"]
```

Comment: -1 because this isn't scalable. Clearly this should be looped.

Comment: Are you seriously going to argue that?

Comment: By simply glancing at the OP, you could easily assume these values are probably coming from some datasource, very likely with a dynamic number of results returned. Provided that's the case (and I'll bet money I don't have that it is), your solution isn't scalable.

Comment: Your point does not present a challenge to grasp, I just chose to answer the question literally. The 'guess the real structure of the array'-game is open for players, but I choose not to compete.

Comment: Then here's the challenge: in real life, would you use a loop or the technique posted in your answer? In answering that, you'll find the reason for my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have them in separate arrays or in one single array? If you have them separately then this would suffice:

```
$array1 = array("posts" => 2, "reactions" => 0);
$array2 = array("posts" => 4, "reactions" => 4);
$array3 = array("posts" => 7, "reactions" => 0);
$array4 = array("posts" => 3, "reactions" => 1);

$sum = $array1['posts'] + $array2['posts'] + $array3['posts'] + $array4['posts'];
echo $sum;
```

Outputs:

```
16
```

Comment: I don't know the exact number of arrays, it changes.

Comment: If you don't know the number of arrays you'll need to store them in an array somehow and then iterate over that array.